# C# LINQ Select table from list with multiple fields

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'd like to select many values from a table with a list.
I have `FabricTable`(Year is `int`):

```
+----+-------+---------+------+
| Id | Color | Texture | Year |
+----+-------+---------+------+
| 1  | Red   | Rough   | 2019 |
+----+-------+---------+------+
| 2  | Green | Soft    | 2019 |
+----+-------+---------+------+
| 3  | Blue  | Rough   | 2019 |
+----+-------+---------+------+
| 4  | Red   | Med     | 2019 |
+----+-------+---------+------+
| 5  | Blue  | Soft    | 2018 |
+----+-------+---------+------+
```

I have `selectedItems` list (year is `int`):

```
+---------+------+
| Texture | Year |
+---------+------+
| Rough   | 2019 |
+---------+------+
| Soft    | 2019 |
+---------+------+
```

I'd like to get the `Id` from table, it should result with `Id` = `1`, `2`, & `3`.

How can I achieve this with Linq in C#? I just need to select by `Texture` & `Year`

Here's what I've tried but I'm not sure how to select from list with multiple values(`selectedItems` is a list but I don't know how to query multiple columns):

```
db.FabricTable.Select(o => o.Texture == selectedItems.Texture && o.Year == selectItems.Year)
```

Comment: what did you try? what did not work? you need to show a bit of what is wrong before asking a question.

Comment: @BrunoBelmondo I've added what I tried, but I get red squiggly line on `selectedItems.Texture` and `selectedItems.Year`

Comment: A `Where` clause will select items from the table, and each item will contain all the properties, including `Id`. For filtering the items based on a list, see Andy's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a compiler error when using `selectedItems.Texture` because `selectedItem` is a list that contains an object with the `Texture` property. You need to check all of the items in the list when searching for the desired items in `FabricTable`:

```
var items = db.FabricTable.Where(o => selectedItems.Any(selectedItem => o.Texture == selectedItem.Texture && o.Year == selectedItem.Year));
```

Comment: This query results in 1 `items` for me, when it should result with many. I guess I should encapsulate this query in `foreach`

Comment: No, you shouldn't need a `foreach`. This will select the first three rows.

Comment: @RufusL Here you can see the `selectedItems` has 4 count, but the `items`only has 1, I've verified in the database that there are 4 items to remove. https://i.imgur.com/XxJ1V6P.gif

Comment: That data is not the same as what you've shown above. You are only selecting values from the first item, and none of the others have exact matches on all three of those properties.

Comment: It was my mistake, I had one of the variables wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication120
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Item> items = new List<Item>() { 
                new Item() { Id = 1, Color = "Red", Texture = "Rough",  Year = 2019},
                new Item() { Id = 2, Color = "Green", Texture = "Soft",  Year = 2019},
                new Item() { Id = 3, Color = "Blue", Texture = "Rough",  Year = 2019},
                new Item() { Id = 4, Color = "Red", Texture = "Soft",  Year = 2018}
            };
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Color", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Texture", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Year", typeof(int));

            foreach (Item item in items.Where(x => (x.Texture == "Rough") && (x.Year == 2019)))
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Color, item.Texture, item.Year });
            }

        }

    }
    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string Texture { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't want to search by hard coded values but by the fields in list, I've edited the OP to be clear on my intent

Comment: so just change to a variable.

Comment: The table has the `Id` not the list, I'm trying to get the `Id` from the table with the list I have.

Comment: The list has the Id, not the table.  If you do not put the Id into the table you can not get it.

Comment: I read the question as "I have a database table that I'd like to use as a datasource for a list", although the OP is fairly unclear because the title says the opposite.