# Gather user-input data from several partial views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have complex data model:

```cs
public class ItemModel
{
    public Item BasicItem;
    public FoodItem FoodItem;
    public LocalItem LocalItem;
}
```

Where each class consist of basic fields(ints, strings etc.). I struggle to collect data in one view and bind it to model - so I decided break down data gathering to 3 partial views, where each one will gather one own class related portion and main view will aggregate them to base model.

I think best way to transfer data to-from partial - is ViewData in this case, but I have no clue - how to *upload* data to ViewData after user entered it?

Comment: what do you mean by "upload data"?

Comment: @dedecos basicly I want a form or some kind of input which will put data inside ViewData on click, or after user deselect input field after entering something

Comment: I usually just build a DataTable dynamically and add columns and rows.  It is then very easy to bind the table to view objects.

Comment: @jdweng Can you explain a little bit more into it with examples? In my case I just have 3 tables with connected classes which already being used in others parts of code, and I just tring to fill them simultaneously cause they have relationships through PK and FKs

Comment: What does the final table look like.  To get results you will need to use a join to combine the 3 classes.  Then the results of the join is a two dimensional table (rows and columns) that you add columns you want in the final view.  In this answer I create a datatable : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57116061/c-sharp-linq-select-table-from-list-with-multiple-fields/57116216#57116216

Comment: @jdweng Problem is - there is no final table.Data from 3 partial views goes into 3 different tables, but cause all 3 tables are context connected(1) PK-FK relations, 2) They describe different parameters of single item (basic parameters like price, title; local availability; food energy - fats, proteins, ccals and such). So even if I gather it all to a single dataTable to dispense afterwards - I still need to hardcode that dataTable model - to much required fields. So, If I afterwards was intended to change one of base models I also will need to change aggregation model -it's bad design to me

Comment: so now, Im looking into breaking my data gathering into 3 separate views where each one will send a form, which after validation will be added to model. So on after 3 steps we will have a proper Item model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I gather data for 3 different classes, I just split up this process into 3 steps each one with own action and view, between actions data is hold up in session and unloaded and processed in final action.

It doesn't seems too elegant, but it is pretty explicit and working.